# How am I deriving this result incorrectly, regarding the relationship between the variance and standard deviation unbiased estimators?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, correlation

Taken directly, from my lecture notes, we are given that

> $$
> \hat{\sigma}_X^2 = \frac{1}{k-1} \sum_{i=1}^k (X_i - \hat{\mu}_X)^2 \\[5mm]
> \hat{\rho} = \frac{1}{k-1} \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(X_i - \hat{\mu}_X)(Y_i - \hat{\mu}_Y)}{\hat{\sigma}_X^2 \cdot \hat{\sigma}_Y^2}
> $$

However, from the formula for $\hat{\sigma}_X^2$, we can deduce that
$$
\hat{\sigma}_X = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{X_i - \hat{\mu}_X}{\sqrt{k-1}}
$$
and hence
$$
\hat{\sigma}_X \cdot \hat{\sigma}_Y = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{X_i - \hat{\mu}_X}{\sqrt{k-1}} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{Y_i - \hat{\mu}_Y}{\sqrt{k-1}} \\[5mm]
= \frac{1}{k-1}\sum_{i=1}^k (X_i - \hat{\mu}_X) (Y_i - \hat{\mu}_Y)
$$
and, thus we have
$$
\hat{\rho} = \frac{1}{k-1} \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{(X_i - \hat{\mu}_X)(Y_i - \hat{\mu}_Y)}{\hat{\sigma}_X^2 \cdot \hat{\sigma}_Y^2} \\[5mm]
= \hat{\rho} = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{\hat{\sigma}_X^2 \cdot \hat{\sigma}_Y^2}{\hat{\sigma}_X^2 \cdot \hat{\sigma}_Y^2} \\[5mm]
= 1
$$
Clearly the correlation coefficient of 2 variables is not always 1, so how have I derieved this result incorrectly?

Comment: First thing I notice: if you're taking square roots of the variance estimator equation, then you cannot bring the square root inside the summation. Another thing: sums are not multiplicative.

Comment: @Dave you mean that $$\hat{\sigma}_X = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{X_i - \hat{\mu}_X}{\sqrt{k-1}}\neq \frac 1 {\sqrt{k-1}}\sum_{i=1}^k {X_i - \hat{\mu}_X}$$because of the index or because of squaring root? and that $$\sum X\times\sum Y\neq \sum XY$$ ?

Comment: I do mean the second part. However, for the first part of my comment, I mean that, if $\hat{\sigma}^2_X=\frac{1}{k-1}\sum^k_{i=1}(X_i-\hat{\mu}_X)^2$, then you cannot take square roots and obtain $\hat{\sigma}_X = \sum_{i=1}^k \frac{X_i - \hat{\mu}_X}{\sqrt{k-1}}$. This is because $\sqrt{\sum(a+b)^2}\neq\sum\sqrt{(a+b)^2}$ in general.